Can the direct object also be the subject if the direct object is a noun that's general enough to also include the subject?
I know that the direct object of a transitive verb isn't to be confused with the subject, but what if the direct object is a noun that is general enough to include the subject?
If I were to describe a device that's only operated by a driver inside of the device such as a car that's used to transport persons, would all cars fit that description of that device since the driver is a person and all cars can only be operated by a person inside of it, or would only cars used to transport persons excluding the driver fit that description since the direct object cannot be the subject?

Please include sample sentences - your second paragraph is rather confusing and it would be simpler if we had examples to work with; you can bracket the part that you think is either the subject or direct object.

The syntactic terms are totally misleading. This is a purely semantic / logistical question, looking at composition of sets and the precise definition of such sets.

It sounds like the barber paradox. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox

I'm not really sure what the second paragraph of your answer is about or how it relates to the first paragraph.

I'm trying to understand the meaning of a statute. The statute says that cars used to transport persons are motor vehicles. Realistically, no car is driverless and all drivers are persons. Does that mean that all cars are motor vehicles? I ask because in the phrase "used to transport persons" the subject would be the personal pronoun "you" and the direct object being transported is "persons" making the phrase to be "automobiles that you use to transport persons are motor vehicles." This would make the direct object "persons" and the subject being the driver. Can they be the same?

The barber paradox is only a paradox if we are to ignore that the paradox was written in English and that English grammer rules must apply. The direct object cannot be the subject. Therefore the barber that shaves himself cannot be a barber as that would make the subject also the direct object. The barber wouldn't be a barber, but a man that only shaves himself.

Questions about interpreting laws are off-topic here; they require legal expertise we don't have. There may be other statues defining the words "car" or "transport" in counterintuitive ways, or there may be case law that settles the issue, or what have you.

Certainly the same physical object can fit into both roles of a sentence. This happens all the time when the direct or indirect object is "him/her/itself".

Can you rephrase the Question making two things more clear, please:
First, what exactly that Question means?
Less usefully, how that belongs here in ELU, rather than in English Language Learners?

In response to Barmar, I understand the direct object can also be the subject, but only when the direct object eliminates all else but the subject as him/her/itself/yourself. However, if the direct object stated does not eliminate all but the subject, such as persons, what then?

In response to Robbie Godwin, I'm trying to understand a statute written in English so for certain, basic grammer rules apply else the statute will make no sense. The statute defines the term motor vehicle to mean an "automobile used to transport persons." Transport hilds the same meaning in the statute as it does when commonly used. Is it proper to include with the term persons the driver? The statute is unclear as to whether or not driver is included other than it  being written in English.
